# Multiplication matrix vector with Python 3.x, numpy e multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, concurrency

I'm writing a benchmark to show the differences in time, cost, speed up, efficiency and effective of a sequential and parallel algorithm that calculate a system of linear equations using Python 3.5, but when i calculate with different processes, the calculation is not performed correctly because the result of the calculation in sequential (and with numpy) is different from that done in parallel. I also noticed that about half of the matrix, each time increasing the number of processes, does not calculate but sets to 0 the i-th position. What am I doing wrong? Where is the mistake and why? This is my code:

```
import random
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
import math, numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
import argparse, sys, os


def creaMatrici(n):
    A = [[random.random() for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
    B = [random.random() for x in range(n)]
    #A^(-1)
    A = np.linalg.inv(A)
    return A,B


def np_moltiplica(a, b):
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    return c


def moltiplica_seriale(A,b,n):
    c = [0 for x in range(n)]
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        for j in range(0,len(A)):
            c[i] += A[i][j] * b[j]
    return c

def moltiplica_parallelo(result_queue, worker_index, chunk_boundary, A,b):
    n = len(A)
    result = []
    for m in range(n):
        output = moltiplica_seriale(
                A[chunk_boundary[0]:chunk_boundary[1],:],b,n)
        result.append(output)

    result_queue.put((worker_index, result))

###########################################################################

def divisione_lavoro(nWorkers, A,b):
    def calcola_partizionamento_lavoro(l, n):
        c = int(math.ceil(len(l)/float(n)))
        return c

    sizePartizionamento = calcola_partizionamento_lavoro(A, nWorkers)
    limitiMatriciDivise = [(i, i+sizePartizionamento) for i in range(0, (len(A)), sizePartizionamento)]

   if nWorkers != len(limitiMatriciDivise):
        return None

    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    processiFigli = []
    for worker_index in range(nWorkers):
        processiFigli.append(                          
               multiprocessing.Process(target=moltiplica_parallelo, 
                             args=(                                                                                
                                   result_queue,
                                   worker_index,
                                   limitiMatriciDivise[worker_index],
                                   A, 
                                   b)
                                      )
                           )

    for c in processiFigli:
        c.start()

    results = [0 for n in range(len(A))]

    for _ in range(nWorkers):
        worker_index, result_chunk = result_queue.get(block=True)
        chunk_boundary = limitiMatriciDivise[worker_index]
        results = result_chunk[0]


    for c in processiFigli:
        c.join()
    return results


    ###########################################################################    

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    n = int(argv[1])


    A,b = creaMatrici(n)




    #########################SERIALE##########################

    start = time.time()
    c = moltiplica_seriale(A,b,n)
    end = time.time()


    duration = (end-start) % 60
    print ('Risultato = ', c)
    print ('\nTempo seriale: %.5f s' % duration)

    #########################NUMPY############################

    start = time.time()
    c = np_moltiplica(A,b)
    end = time.time()

    duration = (end-start) % 60

    print ('\n\nRisultato = ', c)
    print ('\nTempo usando il modulo numpy: %.5f s' %duration)
    print ('\n\n')

    ######################MULTIPROCESSING#######################

    durations = []
    n_children = [1, 2, 4, 8]
    for n in n_children:
        start = time.time()
        result = divisione_lavoro(n, A, b)
        if result is None:
            continue
        duration = (time.time() - start) %60
        if n == 1:
            print ("Risultato calcolato con %s processo figlio: %s" % (n, result))
        else:
            print ("Risultato calcolato con %s processi figli: %s" % (n, result))
        print ("Tempo: %.2f s" % duration)
        print ('\n\n')
        durations.append(duration)

    costo = [n*d for n,d in zip(n_children,durations)]
    speedup = [durations[0]/d for d in durations]
    efficienza = [s/n for s,n in zip(speedup, n_children)]
    efficacia = [s/c for s,c in zip(speedup,costo)]
    for n, costo, speed, efficienza, efficacia in zip(n_children,costo,speedup,efficienza,efficacia):
        if n == 1:
            print ("costo con %s-processo figlio: %.2f" % (n,costo))
            print ("speedup con %s-processo figlio: %.2f" % (n, speed))
            print ("efficienza con %s-processo figlio: %.2f" % (n, efficienza))
            print ("efficacia con %s-processo figlio: %.2f\n" % (n, efficacia))
        else:
            print ("costo con %s-processi figli: %.2f" % (n,costo))
            print ("speedup con %s-processi figli: %.2f" % (n, speed))
            print ("efficienza con %s-processi figli: %.2f" % (n, efficienza))
            print ("efficacia con %s-processi figli: %.2f\n" % (n, efficacia))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: As a general comment, you would be much better off using a version of numpy linked against a multithreaded BLAS library (e.g. OpenBLAS, Intel MKL etc.), which will then automatically parallelize the dot product for floating point matrices. `multiprocessing` carries a lot of overhead, and you're unlikely to see much performance benefit unless your matrix is very large (and even then multithreaded BLAS would still be much quicker).